# Right to left translate animation problem in Android

Tags: android, animation

I have a problem with animation of image that placed out of right or bottom border of parent layout.

This image crops while animation.

First image is original, and second should looks the same, but crops because part of image positioned out of right border.

[Look example here](http://oleg40a.in.ua/upload/AnimationProblem.gif)

The situation with bottom border the same.

Animation:

```
public void onClickDo(View view) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, -100f, 0f, 0f);
    anim.setDuration(1000);

    img.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/problem" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:src="@drawable/problem" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_marginLeft="250dip" android:scaleType="matrix" android:layout_marginTop="110dip"></ImageView>
        <Button android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Button" android:onClick="onClickDo"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for imageview2

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:src="@drawable/problem" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_width="100dip" android:scaleType="matrix" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>
```

Comment: It puts image right of first one, but I want that init image position should be out of border.

Comment: how about this, set the initial visibilty of the view as invisible. set animationlistener for your anim object, then on animation end make your imageview's visibility as visible

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar problem, when I was having two objects (Layout, View or something) which have sharing the same animation.

For example:

```
Image1.startAnimation(myAnimation);
Image2.startAnimation(myAnimation);
```

And myAnimation have `setAnimationListener` where `onAnimationEnd` is set.

So even if you start animation in one after onother Android will have problems with that and will be laggy.

Answer (score 0):

Do this for both your LinearLayout and your RelativeLayout:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

To do this programmatically do:

```
myLinearLayout.setClipChildren(false);
myRelativeLayout.setClipChildren(false);
```